# How to make a Listview with chats?

Tags: java, javafx, chat, scenebuilder

I'm new to programming and I wanted to challenge myself by making something similar(but slightly easier) to ChatGPT with JavaFX and Scenebuilder. I made a GUI with TextArea and TextField for the chats, but I want the different chats to get saved in a ListView and I want to be able to go back and forth between the chats. I just can't figure out how to do this?
I've looked everywhere and every time I think I understand what to do, it just doesn't work.

Does anyone else have an idea what I could do to make it work?

Comment: The network-based stuff in this answer is irrelevant, but the [list-based UI is similar to what you are asking about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70870998/how-to-return-objects-from-inputstream-client-to-a-javafx-controller/70888362#70888362).  That just alternates from side to side based on odd/even rows, but you could assign your own style classes, when updating items, to decide which side of the list a message should show up on.